# Autocomplete TextBox in Asp.Net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, autocomplete, textbox

Can someone please help me to create a Autocomplete TextBox in Asp.Net using C#.
I was trying to create from my end but not working.

I used Oracle 11g as DB.

Below is my code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>

 <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1"  CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false">  
  </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

C# Code:

[WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        return AutoFillProducts(prefixText);

    }
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    private static List<string> AutoFillProducts(string prefixText)
    {
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=172.30.16.30:1522/PUNDEV11;PASSWORD=NCHANNEL;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=NCHANNEL"))
        {

            using (OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = "select * from thread where " + "summary like @Search + '%'";
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", prefixText);
                com.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                List<string> summ = new List<string>();
                using (OracleDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        summ.Add(sdr["summary"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return summ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In Oracle, parameters are not `@parameter_name` but `:parameter_name`.

Comment: Try to change CommandText `like @Search + '%'` to `like @Search || '%'`.